# Is this generalization of runST safe?

Tags: haskell, state-monad

`Control.Monad.ST` in the `base` package contains `runST` to run the strict state-transformer monad:

```
runST :: (forall s. ST s a) -> a
```

However, I need a generalized version of `runST`:

```
runSTCont :: (forall s . (forall b . ST s b -> b) -> a) -> a
runSTCont f = f $ \m -> runST $ unsafeCoerce m
```

My question is: Is this use of `unsafeCoerse` safe?
(I guess so, because as I understand, the only purpose of the index `s` is to prevent to leak `s`-indexed values in the result `a`. The type of `runSTCont` cannot leak `s`-indexed values so it should be OK.)

Note that `runST` can be expressed in terms of `runSTCont` so `runSTCont` is at least as general as `runST`:

```
runST' :: (forall s. ST s a) -> a 
runST' m = runSTCont $ \runST -> runST m
```

Comment: Could you perhaps add a use-case, why you need `ruNSTCont`?

Comment: @PetrPudlák, I have a complex use case. I think I could simplify it, but the most simple use case is the implementation of `runSTCont` itself. I want to avoid comments like "this use case could be implemented also with runST".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't think so:

```
crash = runSTCont crasher where
  crasher :: forall s. (forall b . ST s b -> b) -> Integer
  crasher go =
    let r :: forall a. STRef s (a -> a)
        r = go $ newSTRef id
    in go $ do writeSTRef r (tail . tail)
               f <- readSTRef r
               return $ f (17 :: Integer)
```

The problem is that Haskell lacks the value restriction.

Comment: Is it the problem of this particular `runSTCont` implementation, or its type in general?

Comment: @PetrPudlák it is a problem with the type in general.  It would be fine if Haskell were call-by-name, but because it is implemented with call-by-need you can't generalize effectfull expressions--even if the effect (ie, heaplet you modify) is confined to a "module" which is what `runSTCont` does.

Comment: I would love to better understand this answer. Is there a way to change the provided type to make it safe. It seems the current one is close to allowable, but it leaks access to `unsafeCoerce`. Could this function be better implemented if you had access to the ST constructors?